# 240v 4wire power supply 30 amp breaker,240v 3wire air compressor switch

Tags: electrical

240v power supply has 4 wires red black white ground. my 240v air compressor only has 3 wires white, black,and ground. how do I connect it?

Comment: Not an electrician here, so don't do anything without someone qualified telling you so - but the 4 wire supply is giving you split phase 240V - both black and red give you 120V lines that are 180 degrees out of sync, so connecting red to black gives you 240V. Connecting either red or black to white gives you 120V. In your specific case, I'm not sure what you should do.

Comment: This needs clarification - where is the switch that's mentioned in the title, but not in the question?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I am assuming this question is saying the compressor has white, black, and green leads in the peckerhead.

In the US, the four wire supply should be

- Black - L1 (maybe L2 - doesn't matter)
- Red - L2 (maybe L1 - doesn't matter)
- White - Neutral
- Green - Ground

To test, you should see the following voltages:

- Black to Red = 240V
- Black to White = Red to White = Black to Green = Red to Green = 120V
- and you should read continuity between White and Green.

If the compressor is 240V, it doesn't follow the typical color coding;  the white wire is ungrounded.  The Green on the compressor should be ground, to test you should see continuity between the Green wire and the metal frame of the compressor.  That leaves the black and white on the compressor for the 240V power.  The white on the compressor should NOT show continuity to the Green wire or the metal frame.  (Neither should the black wire on the compressor, for that matter, but it's the white that's off color code and I'd want to carefully verify is power.)

So after all that testing, it's simply

- Supply Black to Compressor Black
- Supply Red to Compressor White
- Supply Green to Compressor Green

Answer (score 1):

4 wire feed to 3 wire hookups will use black, red, and ground. Wire nut the white wire on both ends and tuck it out of the way. I don't recommend cutting the white wire off. This way it's there for possible future upgrades.